# PdfLatex good quality and fast-loading vector images

Tags: graphics, eps

On suggestion of a member of the community of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/, I ask this question also here.

I am writing a paper using PDFLaTeX. In this paper I insert few .eps pictures I export from ArcMap. These images have been exported in format .eps with a dpi of 600.

My problem is that when I build the .pdf and go to the pages with these .eps images, the pdf requires almost one second to display the image and then show the text surrounding it. Furthermore, this resulting pdf, containing 6 .eps images, 15 pages and a few raster images, is 50,000 kB, which seems a lot to me.

The problem is due to the excessive weight of the .eps images (which ranges between few MB and hundreds of MB according to the map I am exporting, I think this cannot be changed), therefore my question is: is there a way to reduce the produced .pdf size and improve the loading speed of vector images in a pdf without changing the input .eps images?

Comment: You might export your images in  .pdf format – or convert to the .pdf format. `epspdf` does an excellent job.

Comment: In some cases, [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/index.htm) can drastically reduce the size of an eps file without changing the image itself. You can then reduce it further by converting to pdf.